# which is the more faster and convenient way to store the data while retrieving it from pdf? database or xml?

Tags: c#, .net

I m trying to convert my pdf document to XHTML format in c#. while retrieving data from pdf, in some cases i need to search for some particular char and replace it with some decimal value in my xhtml file. So which is the better option to store the data which has to be compared with the data in a pdf . is it XML or Database. M using SQL server 2008.

I have referred the following link but still did not get proper solution for my doubt .Can anybody help me out here. thank u

[Where are the differences using XML and MySQL database? Which should I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238749/whare-are-the-differences-using-xml-and-mysql-database-which-should-i-use)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL DB and XML both can be used to store data. The only difference is the format for saving on disk. XML is in pure text form and can be read using any plain text editor. XML has a structure to define and it only has to follows [XML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/).

On the other hand MySQL DB or any other database solution have their own formats for saving and retrieving information. In database systems you normally have to use SQL scripting to retrieve data. They cannot be read using text editors.

SO it totally depends on how you want to structure your data for saving. If it can be easily mapped into a relational database use MYSQL or if you think you can easily save and retreive data from XML you can use that.

Comment: If i consider the speed, which will be faster?

Comment: SQL DB is a little faster if you have big datasets because there is always a SQL engine doing the optimization while retrieving information. XML files are just like plain text and will be very slow if you use big datasets.

Comment: Why do you think that reading a specific XML file is slower than reading a database row?