# How to choose data source (XML file or a data base table)

Tags: java, xml, database

I have 2 data source options:

1. A data base table
2. XML file

How can I choose the data source option in my application? I have 10000 invoice that should be treated in the less time, I can get each invoice data from a data base table or a an XML file.

Comment: Try Sqlite .... One jar file and nothing needed to be installed .... Xml is costly (correct me if am wrong)

Comment: Even I feel xml is expensive... You can go with db - this even helps you in any kind of analysis that might be required in future. Reading xml always requires a parser and lot of effort compared to a simple query that gets executed against the db.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238749/where-are-the-differences-using-xml-and-mysql-database-which-should-i-use) question can help you