# XML as storage for API/ Store data from form in XML-file

Tags: php, python, xml

I have researched APIs and I generally understand how they work and how to use them (HTTP request to API, get data and parse it, etc.), however, for my project I need to use data that I collected myself so I can't just use another database for example. I'm quite new to this so I don't understand a few things. I'll try to explain my plan as clearly as possible. Please let me know if any additional explanation is required.

I have an HTML form which can be filled out and saved. This form is not supposed to be local, but rather on a server

I read a lot about XML-files and API's and I also saw many similar questions on here but I'm not sure what applies to my instance. 
I wanted to store the information from the form in an XML-file. Some people said, that this could be done with JavaScript, some people said this would require some server-side script. What applies in this case? I would guess that I need a server-side script but as I said, I'm kinda at loss here.
I thought I could simply use JavaScript to store whatever is entered into the form and use python or php to create an XML-file in which I store this information. This XML-file would then be used by the API. This is were I have trouble understanding. 
The edited form is supposed to be saved (on the server I guess, so several people can access it), so you can go back to it later and edit it again. How exactly would I implement an API here? Can I just "make" my own XML-file, which the API uses as database? Is there any better way to do this?

I know this probably seems like a stupid question but I really want to understand this so bear with me. I'm very much overwhelmed by this task so I appreciate any help.

Comment: I would take a look at MySQL to store data instead of using XML files

Comment: @ProfGhost Alright, I'll look into that! What is the advantage of doing that?

Comment: SQL is designed for storing and processing data. Take a look here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238749/where-are-the-differences-using-xml-and-mysql-database-which-should-i-use) for a little comparison.

Comment: @ProfGhost Thank you!